# How to authenticate with an ssl certificate through spring security

Tags: ssl, spring-security, ldap, x509

I am working on a grails web app that uses spring security for ldap purposes. We need to setup a situation where instead of the user entering username and password certificates are used instead (or even a rollback to username and password if no certificate is found would be the ideal setup). I've checked online and been trying to no avail, I just can't get it to work. Not sure if I'm not generating the certificates properly or if my config settings in spring security are wrong. Can someone please assist? Thank you

edit: my Config.groovy file looks like this

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_31-b04-415.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts")
 System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","changeit")


 grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerDn = 'cn=administrator,cn=users,dc=ldap,dc=example,dc=com'
 grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerPassword = 'password'



grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.server = 'ldaps://ldap.example.com:636/'


grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.ignorePartialResultException = true // typically needed for Active Directory

   grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.base = 'dc=ldap,dc=example,dc=com'
   grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.filter="sAMAccountName={0}" // for Active Directory you need this
   grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.searchSubtree = true
   grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.auth.hideUserNotFoundExceptions = false
```

Comment: please share the configuration files and the code used to check for certificates.